# How do I execute code every frame in Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ionic-framework

First of all, I'm completely new to Ionic, React and JSX and fairly new to JS in general. For learning purposes I want to play around with something like a "mini experimental idle game".

Now, I'm trying to update some field every frame and do some calculations.
I know this will be quite CPU-intensive and battery-draining (on mobile devices) but I specifically want that behavior.
I have set my `tsconfig.json { "strict": false }`, so I can use plain JS, which I'm a bit more used to.

So say, I have this element:

```
var count = 0;

<IonCardTitle>
    <span id="fieldCount">{count}</span> Things
</IonCardTitle>
```

What I know want is to run something like this every single frame:

```
if(count < 1000000) {
    document.querySelector('#moneycount').innerHTML = count.toString();
    count++;
}
```

How would I go about changing the `.innerHTML` of the element **every frame** and increment `count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forced React to render continuously by working from Gabriels answer.

I added the following into the index.tsx:

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}, 50); // every 50ms
```

According to [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) the renderer only updates what needs to be updated when called so I'm confident this is actually the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval`, and increment count every interval. For example:

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    count = count + 1;
    if (count >= 1000000) {
        // use clearInterval to stop interval execution
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 10); // every 10ms, could be more or less depending on your needs
```

There is no need to update `innerHTML` since your component renders count dynamically.

Comment: I've added your suggestion to the ExplroeContainer.tsx (I'm in the sidemenu-template) and it counts up to 2 while the page is loading and then stops. How can I get the interval to run continously?

Comment: I just realized that the interval keeps running in the background but Ionic/React doesn't update the displayed value at runtime but only when the page is reloaded (e.g. by navigating to another page and then back). I need it to update in realtime. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm glad it helped!